# Cannot inspect arguments passed to a Jest mocked object

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a fairly straight-forward Typescript class and method.  I want to test this method using Jest to mock out this method's dependencies:

```
import {DynamoWorkflow} from '..';
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class PipelineService {
    getCoverageByServiceName(serviceName: string): Promise<QueryResult<PipelineEvent>> {
        return new DynamoWorkflow().queryPipelineEvents(serviceName);
    }
}
```

In my test I want to confirm that the argument passed to the method `.queryPipelineEvents()` is what I expect.  I'm finding this difficult to accomplish.

Here is my current test:

```
//setup mock data...
const mockPipelineEvent: PipelineEvent = new PipelineEvent();
mockPipelineEvent.aut = "fake data";
const mockPipelineEvents: PipelineEvent[] = [mockPipelineEvent];
const mockQueryResult = {results: mockPipelineEvents, total: 1};

//setup mock dependency...
jest.mock('../../../../workflows/dynamoworkflow', () => {
  return {
    DynamoWorkflow: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        queryPipelineEvents: () => Promise.resolve(mockQueryResult),
      };
    })
  };
});

describe("PipelineService", () => {
  const mockDynamo = mocked(DynamoWorkflow, true);
    
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockDynamo.mockClear(); 
  })

  it("getCoverageByServiceName returns same data as db supplies", () => {
    const methodArg = "foo-service";
    const serviceUnderTest = new PipelineService();
    const actualResult = serviceUnderTest.getCoverageByServiceName(methodArg);

    // Test #1: confirm the dependency was called
    expect(mockDynamo).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); //PASSES

    // Test #2: confirm the dependency method was called with the correct argument
    const mockedDynamoInstance = mockDynamo.mock.instances[0];
    const mockedDynamoMethod = mockedDynamoInstance.queryPipelineEvents;
    expect(mockedDynamoMethod.mock.calls[0][0]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(methodArg);  //ERROR HERE on .mock

    // Test #3: confirm the result is what we expect
    expect(actualResult).resolves.toEqual(mockQueryResult); //PASSES
  });
})
```

This code will not compile.  The message is `Property 'mock' does not exist on type '(serviceName: string) => Promise<QueryResult<PipelineEvent>>'.ts(2339)`.

The errant chunk of code I took [directly from Jest's own documentation.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock)

I've tried `expect(mockDynamo.queryPipelineEvents).toBeCalledWith(methodArg);` but that won't compile either, the error saying: `Property 'queryPipelineEvents' does not exist on type 'MockedObjectDeep<typeof DynamoWorkflow>'.ts(2339)`

I've also tried `expect(mockDynamo.mock.instances[0].queryPipelineEvents).toBeCalledWith(methodArg);`.  It compiles and runs fine but fails with the message:

```
    expect(received).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has value: undefined

      44 |     // expect(mockedDynamoMethod.mock.calls[0][0]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(methodArg);
      45 |     // expect(mockDynamo.queryPipelineEvents).toBeCalledWith(methodArg);
    > 46 |     expect(mockDynamo.mock.instances[0].queryPipelineEvents).toBeCalledWith(methodArg);
         |                                                              ^
      47 | 
      48 |     // Test #3: confirm the result is what we expect
      49 |     expect(actualResult).resolves.toEqual(mockQueryResult);
```

Can somebody help me understand how I can confirm that a mocked method's arguments were as expected?

Answer (score 0):

A co-worked was working on different tests and stumbled onto the answer for this.  The key was assigning the mock method to the object and method being mocked.  Throw out all the mocking from the original code and replace it with this:

```
jest.mock('../../../../workflows/dynamoworkflow');
const mockMethod = jest.fn();
mockMethod.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockQueryResult));
DynamoWorkflow.prototype.queryPipelineEvents = mockMethod; //<- key here!
```

Here's the complete, working test:

```
describe("PipelineService", () => {

  it("getCoverageByServiceName returns same data as db supplies", () => {
    //setup mock data...
    const mockPipelineEvent: PipelineEvent = new PipelineEvent();
    mockPipelineEvent.aut = "fake data";
    const mockPipelineEvents: PipelineEvent[] = [mockPipelineEvent];
    const mockQueryResult = {results: mockPipelineEvents, total: 1};

    //setup mock...
    jest.mock('../../../../workflows/dynamoworkflow');
    const mockMethod = jest.fn();
    mockMethod.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockQueryResult));
    DynamoWorkflow.prototype.queryPipelineEvents = mockMethod;

    //exercise the method we're testing...
    const methodArg = "foo-service";
    const serviceUnderTest = new PipelineService();
    const actualResult = serviceUnderTest.getCoverageByServiceName(methodArg);

    // and test...
    expect(mockMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(methodArg);
    expect(actualResult).resolves.toEqual(mockQueryResult);
  });

})
```